# VLC for Android -- resume from stopped position when clicking on History

Tags: history, vlc

Let's say I'm listening to a 14 hour long audiobook (on VLC for Android). I pause at the 5 hour point.

Then I don't use VLC for a week.

Then I go back, and go to History, and click on the title of that audiobook. In my experience, it starts playing from the start of that file. I want it to start playing from the 5 hour point. Is there a way to do this? (If not, it would be a nice feature to have.)

Comment: Must be somewhere in the Settings. If not you can give feedback on that.

Comment: Same issue here: there are parameters to resume playback after a call or when a headset is plugged in, but not when the app has simply be restarted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I was unable to get VLC to do it, but I found the perfect alternative app for it:

Simple Audiobook Player:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mdmt.sabp.free&hl=en_US

It only plays audio (no video), however it can remember the "last played" history point for all my audio files.

Answer (score 7):

I too was looking for this but I haven't found a direct answer for VLC on android. There is an option under `Settings -> Extra Setting -> Video -> Ask confirmation to resume`. But it appears to only work for video and there is currently no equivalent setting under the audio settings.

I did come across another app called [Smart AudioBook Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ak.alizandro.smartaudiobookplayer) which has this feature. Unfortunately it's not totally free like VLC but there is a free mode (I'm not 100% sure on the differences).  The cool thing is it will remember your location in multiple books not just the last one you played.

Answer (score 2):

I just found a way to do it (with VLC 3.0.13 and Android 7.1.2). When you are done listening to your audio file do not pause it, but quit VLC application by tapping on the cross in the notification pop-up.

[[image: VLC Notification pop-up]

When reopening VLC, go to "history", select the audio file you were listening and that's it: it will resume at the point where you exited VLC app.

N.B.: You can listen to multiple audio files and VLC will keep in memory each quitting point.

Answer (score 2):

Resume audio playback position does work in VLC-Android v3.2.7 when both these conditions are met

- the audio file's ID3 `genre` tag is one of `podcast`, `audiobooks`, `audiobook`, `speech`, `vocal` (or if the file is untagged and > 15 minutes long)  ([source code](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android/blob/3.2.x/medialibrary/src/org/videolan/medialibrary/interfaces/media/AbstractMediaWrapper.java#L429))
- the last time the file was played playback ended with `stop` (longpress pause button)

Resume does *not* currently work if the last playing of the file ended with `pause` (tap pause button).
But a fix for that is [in progress](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android/issues/1205).